# Dictionary has duplicate keys in c# with toDictionary

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, duplicates

I'm trying to eliminate the duplicate strings from the list with the list.District() and the toDictionary but it doesn't work.

Any recommendation how I can eliminate the duplication code with Linq?

here is my code

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, int> SensorValues => InOrderSensorValues
      .ToDictionary(
         x => x.Split(':')[0].ToUpper(), 
         x => int.Parse(x.Split(':')[1]));
```

And then i want to split the words as above

Comment: You're not using `Distinct` anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What is `InOrderSensorValues`? What did you expect `SensorValues` to be? What is it actually?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the problem you are seeing. That should include a small sample of the data in `InOrderSensorValues` that produces the the duplicates.

Comment: @Darren, I used it but I doesnt work with toDictionary

Comment: @Sweeper, SensorValues is a simple list with a string value, such as "Sensor1:2" and I'm trying to split the string. I want to put the Sendor1 as a key into the dictionary and value of 2 etc

Comment: @CsibiNorbert Can't you just do `Distinct` before `ToDictionary`?

Comment: @Sweeper i cannot, it throws an error, cannot even build

Comment: @Sweeper That wouldn't help - the duplicate keys come from the `Split`, and a `Distinct` is against the whole object. An extension method `DistinctBy` is what would be used, or `ToLookup` then `ToDictionary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToDictionary()` fails on duplicate keys by design. You can either filter out your data, or insert a `GroupBy()` before it to eliminate duplicate entries.

Lastly, you can also consider `ToLookup()` which does tolerate duplicate keys.

Adding `GroupBy()` would be like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> SensorValues => 
     InOrderSensorValues.GroupBy(x => x.Split(':')[0].ToUpper()).
     ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => int.Parse(g.First().Split(':')[1]));
```

Comment: It says g does not exist in the context. When i say g.First()

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select` to save the `Split` string and then `GroupBy` the key, then create a `Dictionary` using a selection method for the multiple values - I chose `First`:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> SensorValues => InOrderSensorValues
      .Select(sv => sv.Split(':'))
      .GroupBy(svp => svp[0].ToUpper(), svp => svp[1])
      .ToDictionary(
         kvp => kvp.Key, 
         kvp => int.Parse(kvp.First()));
```